# Basic script that works fine on desktop but not loading on my Android?

Tags: android, processing, sketchware

I'm sorry for this basic question I'm new to this android thing...and gotta start struggling somewhere...(Please be gentle)

Have a basic sketch in processing that shows the computer's camera view in a window. Works fine on the computer. It doesn't load on my android. Just hangs and pretends to be building forever. Not sure if it has to do with camera permissions and I'm a nubbie at this so have no idea how to find out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

The code:

```
import processing.video.*;

Capture video;

void setup() {
  size(320, 240);
  video = new Capture(this, 320, 240);
  video.start();
}

void captureEvent(Capture video) {
  video.read();
}

void draw() {
 image(video, 0, 0);
}
```

As it compiles this is the only apparent 'problem' but it doesn't come back as an error.
**Exception in thread "Thread-203" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "list" is null
**

Comment: Do you have a video camera plugged into your Android device?

Comment: No...I want to use the phone's camera. That code works on both my macbook camera and a plug in webcam....but just spins when I compile the app onto the phone.

Comment: https://www.mobileprocessing.org/cameras.html . Uses ketai.camera.* library.